# R vector only giving out 49 elements

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the NFL website for player data and I successfully scraped the tables. Then I was trying to scrape the players height and weight and when I was doing so, I looped over 50 elements in data1 but my resulting vectors "heights" and "weights" are of length 49 and I cannot seem to figure out why. Help!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(httr)


qb_url1 = read_html("http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&statisticCategory=PASSING&season=2019&seasonType=REG&experience=&tabSeq=0&qualified=false&Submit=Go")
QB1 = html_nodes(qb_url1, css = "table")
QBdata1 = html_table(QB1, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[[1]]

data1 <- qb_url1 %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_attr('href')
heights <- c()
weights <- c()

for(i in data1) {
  url <- str_c("https://www.nfl.com", i)
  page <- read_html(url)
  height <- str_sub(html_nodes(page, ".player-team-links+ p"), 36, 39)
  weight <- str_sub(html_nodes(page, ".player-team-links+ p"), 74, 77)
  heights <- c(heights, height)
  weights <- c(weights, weight)
}
add_column(QBdata1, height = heights, weight = weights)
```

Comment: Without looking at the data, it is entirely feasible that data is *missing*. Have you verified that the data is apparently present and meaningful on the actual website?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the 44th entry in `data1` does not follow the same structure as others.  You can verify this with below code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

output <- map(str_c("https://www.nfl.com", data1), ~{
  temp <- .x %>% read_html %>% html_nodes(".player-team-links+ p")
  substring(temp, c(36, 74), c(38, 76))
})

output[[44]]
#character(0)
```

You need to extract that entry manually after changing the code for it as below.

```
temp <- str_c("https://www.nfl.com", data1)[44] %>%
        read_html %>%
        html_nodes("div.player-info") %>%
        html_text() 

height <- sub(".*Height: (\\d-\\d).*", "\\1", temp)
weight <- sub(".*Weight: (\\d+).*", "\\1", temp)

output[[44]] <- c(height, weight)
```

Comment: Nice + . Is .x specific to tidyverse? And what purpose does the ~ perform here? I'm trying to understand how it fits together so concisely.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, `.x` is used while using a formula syntax (`~`) similar to `x` in anonymous function (`lapply(list, function(x) ...`) . We can use both of this interchangeably here.

Comment: thanks... It looked like an anonymous function. Was just reading the help("~") trying to understand the interchange.

Comment: `help("~") ` is different from `~` used here I think. For the one used here, you can refer `?map` specifically in `.f` part of function.